# Set a managed bean property while iterating a p:dataGrid / p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datagrid, datatable, jsf-2.2

I have three tables in MySQL database.

- category (excluded from this question)
- sub_category
- product

The relationship between these tables is intuitive - one-to-many in the order in which they appear.

---

I'm iterating through a list of `SubCategory`, `List<SubCategory>` using [`<p:dataGrid>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datagrid.jsf) as follows.

```
<p:dataGrid var="row" value="#{subCategoryManagedBean}" rows="2" first="0" columns="1" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" pageLinks="10" lazy="true" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%;">

        <!--Here set #{row.subCatId} to the associated managed bean, does not seem possible-->

        <!--<p:carousel var="prodRow" value="#{row.productSet.toArray()}" numVisible="4" pageLinks="5" headerText="#{row.subCatName}" style="text-align: left;">
            <p:graphicImage library="fileUpload" name="product_image/medium/#{prodRow.productImageSet.toArray()[0].prodImage}"/>
        </p:carousel>-->

    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:ajax event="page" onstart="PF('blockDataPanelUIWidget').block()" oncomplete="PF('blockDataPanelUIWidget').unblock()"/>
</p:dataGrid>
```

While iterating over `List<SubCategory>`, I want to set the `id` of each sub category, `subCatId` (of type `Long`) to the managed bean in question so that a list of products associated with each sub category can be fetched before showing products in [`<p:carousel>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/carousel.jsf) Is it possible?

---

**Additional information:**

Each object of `SubCategory` in `List<SubCategory>` has a set of products, `Set<Product>` already fetched and they are displayed in `<p:carousel>` too as show in the commented code in XHTML but I need to fetch only top five products of each sub category after sorting a list of products of each sub category in descending order.

This seems possible only if a list of products is queried for every sub category while iterating over `List<SubCategory>`.

<sub>Please suggest, if there are some other ways round. Anyway, I need to display a sub category-wise list of products in a tabular format - sub category1 `->` show its top 5 products in the first row of `<p:dataGrid>`, sub category2 `->` show its top 5 products in the second row of `<p:dataGrid>` and so on.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do it. This is how your `<p:carousel>` should be:

```
<p:carousel var="prodRow" value="#{mrBean.getProducts(row.subCatId)}" numVisible="4"
            pageLinks="5" headerText="#{row.subCatName}" style="text-align: left;">
    <p:graphicImage library="fileUpload" name="product_image/medium/#{prodRow.productImageSet.toArray()[0].prodImage}"/>
</p:carousel>
```

This is the `@ManagedBean`:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MrBean {
    ...
    public List<Product> getProducts(Long subCatId) {
        // Fetch your top 5 products here
    }
    ...
}
```